# I want to print the whole result coming from the server - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularJs. I'm doing a university project with spring boot and angularJs.

I want to print all the result coming from the server.

here is my codes.

app.js

```
'use strict';

    var App = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

HomeController.js

```
 'use strict';


App.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'HomeService', function($scope, HomeService) {


$scope.getDeviceList = function () {
        HomeService.getDeviceList()
          .then (function success(response){ 
              $scope.details = responce.data;
              $scope.errorMessage = '';
          },
          function error(response){
              $scope.errorMessage = 'Error occured!!!';
              $scope.message = response.data.message;
        });
    }

}]);
```

HomeService.js

```
'use strict';

App.service('HomeService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){


var REST_SERVICE_URI = '/customer';




this.getDeviceList = function getDeviceList(){
    return $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI + '/get_device_list')

}

}]);
```

home.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Ncheck Surveilance</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular-resource.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../controller/RegistrationController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../controller/HomeController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../service/RegistrationService.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../service/HomeService.js"></script>

      </head>

</html>   
<body ng-controller="HomeController">

    Logged in user: <b th:inline="text"> [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]] </b>
    <br>
    <span class="panel-title">Registered Devices</span>
     <span>
            <button id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"   ng-click="getDeviceList()" >Show</button>
                 {{details}}
            {{error}}
    </span>
   <div>
        Hello : <b th:inline="text">  </b>
        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
       </form>
   </div> <br/>  
</body>
```

My problem is when I click "Show" button I get a error (Possibly unhandled rejection: {}) in the web browser console.

Comment: can you confirm if your service is returning any data properly?

Comment: Do you actually receive a `json` encoded response from your backend ?

Comment: This is a well know problem of the 1.6 version.. http://www.codelord.net/2017/08/20/angular-1-dot-6-s-possibly-unhandled-rejection-errors/

Comment: There is a typo in your HomeController when you are setting your details variable: `$scope.details = responce.data;`; should be `$scope.details = response.data;`.

Comment: yes. my service is returning all data properly when I click the button. the problem is it's not printing. @RakeshBurbure

Comment: yes. I receive. @Korte